# Defining routes for Camel

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I'm newbie to camel and by going through it's documentation I figured it out that how routes are configured for various endpoints like JMS and web service, but I have a confusion regarding configuring a route for scenario described below:-

Let's suppose I have a spring controller which receives data and then decides where it need to transfer for instance if the data contains parameter X then it need to invoke a service otherwise all data will be sent to a queue (from where other services will take care of data). I figured the latter part i.e. how to define a route in case of parameter other than X, but the former part is bit confusing to me.
Please suggest and point my mistake if there is any.

Comment: Can you better explain what your question is?

Comment: Ok, I just need to define two routes in camel where I can route the incoming request on the basis of their parameters, out of two routes one route will transfer data to queue on the basis of parameters (say X) in request, and if the parameter is not X then the request should be redirected to another bean's method.

Comment: Sounds a bit like the content based router - study the EIPs is a good idea!!! - http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion Claus, this was something I required.